# How to solve-:(String is not a valid coordinate type) error in neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working on neo4j database, I am very new to it working with nodes but suddenly I got an error in a query.I am not able to solve this I have spent 8 hrs to solve it but still not getting any solution.i am using nodejs on the server side.

My Neo4j Query:

```
MATCH (a : User)-[p : POSTS]->(b), (b)-[category : category]->(categoryNode : Category) 
WITH a, p, b, categoryNode, toFloat(distance (point({latitude : 23.0751926, longitude : 72.5256395}), 
 point({latitude : b.latitude, longitude : b.longitude})) / 1000) as distance 
WHERE (b.banned <> 1 OR NOT EXISTS(b.banned)) AND (distance <= 30) 
 AND (NOT EXISTS(b.sold) OR b.sold = 0) AND (b.latitude IS NOT NULL AND b.longitude IS NOT NULL) 
 AND (EXISTS (b.priceInUSD) OR b.priceInUSD IS NOT NULL) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (commentsBy : User)-[c : Commented]->(b) 
RETURN DISTINCT a.username AS username, a.fullName AS fullName,
 a.profilePicUrl AS profilePicUrl, toInt(p.postedOn) AS postedOn, 
 p.type AS postsType, b.postId AS postId, b.productsTagged AS productsTagged, 
 b.place AS place, b.latitude AS latitude, b.longitude AS longitude, b.city AS city, 
 b.countrySname AS countrySname, b.mainUrl AS mainUrl, 
 b.thumbnailImageUrl AS thumbnailImageUrl, b.postCaption AS postCaption, b.hashTags AS hashtags, 
 b.imageCount AS imageCount, b.containerHeight AS containerHeight, 
 b.containerWidth AS containerWidth, b.productsTaggedCoordinates AS productsTaggedCoordinates, 
 b.hasAudio AS hasAudio, categoryNode.name AS category, categoryNode.mainUrl AS categoryMainUrl, 
 categoryNode.activeImageUrl AS cateoryActiveImageUrl, toFloat(b.priceInUSD) / 0.01623113104640268 AS price, 
 "HTG" AS currency , toInt(b.priceInUSD) AS priceInUSD, b.productName AS productName, 
 b.likes AS likes, b.thumbnailUrl1 AS thumbnailUrl1, b.imageUrl1 AS imageUrl1, 
 b.containerHeight1 AS containerHeight1, b.containerWidth1 AS containerWidth1, 
 b.imageUrl2 AS imageUrl2, b.thumbnailUrl2 AS thumbnailUrl2, b.containerHeight2 AS containerHeight2, 
 b.containerWidth2 AS containerWidth2, b.thumbnailUrl3 AS thumbnailUrl3, 
 b.imageUrl3 AS imageUrl3, b.containerHeight3 AS containerHeight3, 
 b.containerWidth3 AS containerWidth3, b.thumbnailUrl4 AS thumbnailUrl4, 
 b.imageUrl4 AS imageUrl4, b.containerHeight4 AS containerHeight4, b.containerWidth4 AS containerWidth4, 
 COLLECT (DISTINCT {commentBody : c.comments, commentedByUser : commentsBy.username, 
  commentedOn : c.createTime, commentId : ID(c)})[0..5] AS commentData, distance 
ORDER BY distance ASC, priceInUSD ASC, postedOn DESC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 20;
```

after executing this query I am getting an error like this:

```
{
  "signature": 127,
  "fields": [
    {
      "code": "Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError",
      "message": "String is not a valid coordinate type."
    }
  ],
  "timings": {
    "type": "client"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: @InverseFalcon i am using  3.1.1

Comment: For all `b` nodes, are there any string types for `b.latitude` or `b.longitude`?

Answer (score 3):

The `b.latitude` and `b.longitude` values may be strings (not floating point numbers), which are not valid types for coordinates.

Try changing this snippet:

```
point({latitude : b.latitude, longitude : b.longitude})
```

to this:

```
point({latitude : TOFLOAT(b.latitude), longitude : TOFLOAT(b.longitude)})
```

(Or, to be more efficient: change those property values to be floating point numbers in the first place).